# ORA-31603: object "FKSL6L09UUXICDX66MNPLQ0DI63" of type CONSTRAINT not found in schema "AIBLNGZDB"

Tags: oracle, constraints, sqlplus, ddl

I'm trying to get all constraint `DDL` from `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` using `SQL PLUS`. But `ORA-31603` arise. Like this constraint there have more constraint where name are same but their Owner are different.

I try this by following query

```
-- Run this script in SQL*Plus.

-- don't print headers or other crap
set heading off;
set echo off;
set pagesize 0;      

-- don't truncate the line output
-- trim the extra space from linesize when spooling
set long 99999;      
set linesize 32767;  
set trimspool on;    

-- don't truncate this specific column's output
col object_ddl format A32000;

spool AIBLNGZDB_CONSTRAINT_ddl.sql;

SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('CONSTRAINT', constraint_name, owner) || ';' AS object_ddl
FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE 
      OWNER = 'AIBLNGZDB'
--  AND OBJECT_TYPE IN (
--      'CONSTRAINT'
----     'INDEX'
----    , 'SEQUENCE'
----    , 'VIEW'
--  )
ORDER BY
    OWNER
--  , OBJECT_TYPE
;

spool off;

SET LINESIZE 500
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider joining `all_constraints` to `all_objects`. That should also help with dropped constraints (as they are contained in recycle bin, and you can't get their DDL):

```
SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints;

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
BIN$7gsQxw2vJ/LgU8lkAQo5GQ==$0
BIN$7gsQxw2rJ/LgU8lkAQo5GQ==$0
SYS_C00106654
<snip>

SQL>   SELECT    DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('CONSTRAINT', c.constraint_name, c.owner)
  2           || ';' AS object_ddl
  3      FROM all_constraints c
  4     WHERE c.owner = 'SCOTT'
  5  ORDER BY c.owner;
ERROR:
ORA-31603: object "BIN$7gsQxw2vJ/LgU8lkAQo5GQ==$0" of type CONSTRAINT not found
in schema "SCOTT"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 5805
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 8344
ORA-06512: at line 1



no rows selected

SQL>
```

---

But, joining `all_objects` makes a difference:

```
SQL>   SELECT    DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('CONSTRAINT', c.constraint_name, c.owner)
  2           || ';' AS object_ddl
  3      FROM all_constraints c
  4           JOIN all_objects o
  5              ON     o.owner = c.owner
  6                 AND o.object_name = c.table_name
  7     WHERE c.owner = 'SCOTT'
  8  ORDER BY c.owner;

OBJECT_DDL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "SCOTT"."STUDENTS" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("ROLLNOSTUD")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USER_DATA"  ENABLE;


  ALTER TABLE "SCOTT"."DEPARTMENT" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("DEPT_NO")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255
  TABLESPACE "USER_DATA"  ENABLE;
<snip>
```

Comment: Constraint which is not found from my query is an active constraint.

Comment: Obviously (according to its name). But, did you - nonetheless - do as I suggested? What was the result?

Comment: From your query I got following error.

`ORA-31603: object "FK_DEPTNO" of type CONSTRAINT not found in schema "SCOTT"`
`ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 6069`
`ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 8666`
`ORA-06512: at line 1`

& with alter statement I got this `ORA-02260: table can have only one primary key`

Comment: That would be because you're trying to extract DDL for a **foreign key constraint**. In GET_DDL, you'd then use **REF_CONSTRAINT**, not just CONSTRAINT, i.e. `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('REF_CONSTRAINT', ...`

Comment: I want to extract all constraint DDL at a time by using `GET_DDL`. So for this what should I do?

Comment: Do it separately.

Comment: If I do it separately then please help me with name of constraint like `REF_CONSTRAINT`.

It would be good to me if I get all constraint at a time. Cause I need to run multiple time to get DDL & further perform with those DDL.

Answer (score 0):

There are several difficulties with extracting constraint DDL. As Littlefoot pointed out, you need to exclude recycle bin objects and REF_CONSTRAINTS. You may also need to exclude the other [constraint types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_CONSTRAINTS.html#GUID-9C96DA92-CFE0-4A3F-9061-C5ED17B43EFE)  "O" ("With read only, on a view"), and "V" ("With check option, on a view"). Those two other constraint types will show up as part of a view's DDL, so they can be ignored in the below query.

```
--Reference constraints:
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('REF_CONSTRAINT', constraint_name) || ';' as object_ddl
from all_constraints
where owner = 'AIBLNGZDB'
    and constraint_type = 'R'
    and constraint_name not like 'BIN$%'

union all

--Other kinds of constraints.
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('CONSTRAINT', constraint_name) || ';' as object_ddl
from all_constraints
where owner = 'AIBLNGZDB'
    and constraint_type not in ('O', 'V', 'R')
    and constraint_name not like 'BIN$%';
```

Comment: Thank you. It's really helpful for me to get all constraints DDL at a time.